Invoking dbt macro directly from the DAG file in Airflow using PythonOperator
I am trying to invoke a macro directly from the DAG file as a task rather than being invoked from any of the model. Below is the code, I am using which is not working as expected, please help on this,
dbt_project_path="/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/project_folder"
dbt_profile_path="/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/project_folder/.dbt"

def run_dbt_macro(**kwargs):
    dbt_executable = execution_config.dbt_executable_path
    print(f"the path is: {dbt_executable}") 

    dbt_command = [
        dbt_executable, 
        'run-operation',
        'macro_name',
        '--project-dir', dbt_project_path,
        '--profiles-dir', dbt_profile_path,
        '--profile', 'default',
        '--target', running_env,
        '--debug'
    ]
    print(f"the command is: {dbt_command}")

    try:
        process = subprocess.run(dbt_command, capture_output=True, text=True)
        print("STDOUT:", process.stdout)
        print("STDERR:", process.stderr)
        # process = subprocess.Popen(dbt_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        # stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

        # print(f"STDOUT: {stdout.decode('utf-8')}")
        # if stderr:
        #     print(f"STDERR: {stderr.decode('utf-8')}")

        if process.returncode != 0:
            raise Exception(f"dbt command failed with exit code {process.returncode}")
        
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Error while running dbt macro: {e}")
    return process.stdout,process.stderr

run_macro = PythonOperator(
     task_id="run_specific_macro",
     python_callable=run_dbt_macro,
)

The code does not give any errors neither invoke/run the macro.
Use case/motivation
The code should pick up the specific macro and execute it successfully from the DAG file, rather than invoking from any of the models. The macro runs perfectly outside of airflow using the command dbt run-operation macro_name
